# Youtube API v3: regionCode

Tags: api, youtube

I am new in this domain, and I want to create a program which receives the latest videos released in a given country.

For example:

```
resultat = youtube.search().list(
    part='id,snippet',
    regionCode='FR',
    maxResults=10,
    publishedBefore='2017-08-14T00:00:00Z',
    publishedAfter='2017-08-13T00:00:00Z',
    type='video',
    order="date"
).execute()
```

I want to receive the latest videos released between 2017-08-13 and 2017-08-14

But I found Japanese and Arabic videos and other language videos and I think these videos are published in other countries.

I want to know if I have retrieved all the videos from this code between 2017-08-13 and 2017-08-14 in FR?

Comment: According to documentation, it should work this way. My guess would be that those unwanted videos simply do not have their region code set properly ...

Comment: Thank you, then there is not a solution to just retrieve the videos of a chosen country?

Comment: If those videos are pretending to be something they are not, then no.